# Half Adder Using 4069 and 4011 Chips

Tags: wiring, adder

I am having trouble designing a wiring diagram for a half adder using the following two chips:

- [CD4069](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/CD/CD4069UBC.pdf) (hex inverter)
- [HEF4011](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/HEF4011B.pdf) (quad 2-input NAND)

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can make any logic gate from NAND gates:

[image]

Convert the usual representation of a half-adder (see below) into its equivalent in NAND gates.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to construct a half adder using *exactly* the gates they have on hand, though? The NAND equivalents you've given would require more gates than are available in a single HEF4011.

Comment: @duskwuff You can do this with four NANDs and one inverter, combining the equivalent circuits above.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As  Mr.Crosley (correctly) points out the **sum** part of the circuit is a 2 input EXOR made up from 4 x 2-input NAND gates. This is exactly a single 4011. The carry is a 2-input AND gate. (NAND + INVERT). Looking at the circuit the output C is A NAND B. By using one gate from the 4069 this can easily be changed to A AND B (= sum).

Comment: Yes, that was my intended solution, which I did not post because the usual policy here is to give hints for homework (which I did) but not complete solutions.  Note the OP was asked if they had done any work so far and there was no reply.  Now they don't have to.